# Strange Characters In Decrypted Json Web Token Data

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, jwt

I'm encrypting the user informations by `SymmetricCryptograper` which I'm placing into JWT. But, when I call back that token with encrypted infos and try to decrypt these infos back, I get weird characters.

So, I ran through on StackOverflow and saw that the real problem might be related with lack of `Encoding.UTF8` so I put them on `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` instances in `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods. But, this didn't work out too unfortunally.

Here is my class which contains Encrypt and Decrypt methods.

```
public class DESCryptographer : SymmetricCryptographer
{
    private readonly DESCryptoServiceProvider _des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    public DESCryptographer(string key) : base(key)
    {

        _des.GenerateIV();
        IV = _des.IV;
    }

    public DESCryptographer(string key, string iV) : base(key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iV))
    {

    }

    public override string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        ICryptoTransform cEncryptor = _des.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key), IV);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
            cEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.Write(plainText);
        writer.Flush();
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        writer.Flush();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }

    public override string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream
            (Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText));
        ICryptoTransform cDecryptor = _des.CreateDecryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key), IV);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
            cDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Below is my class which publish JWT:

```
public string PublishToken(string email, string password, string digitCode, int expireMinutes, int notBeforeMinutes)
    {
        var hmac = new HMACSHA256();
        var key = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.Key);
        var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var now = DateTime.Now;

        SymmetricCryptograperManager symmetricCryptograperManager = new SymmetricCryptograperManager();
        var schema = symmetricCryptograperManager.GetSymmetricCryptographer(SymmetricCryptographyStrategy.DESCryptography, "000" + digitCode);
        string encryptedEmail = schema.Encrypt(email);
        string encryptedPassword = schema.Encrypt(password);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, encryptedEmail),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Hash, encryptedPassword),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.SerialNumber, digitCode)
            }),
            NotBefore = now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(notBeforeMinutes)),
            Expires = now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(expireMinutes)),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var stoken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(stoken);

        return token;
    }
```

Lastly, below is my token authentication class.

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        SymmetricCryptograperManager symmetricCryptograperManager = new SymmetricCryptograperManager();            

        HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authorization == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (authorization.Scheme != "Basic")
        {
            return;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing Credentials", request);
            return;
        }

        byte[] credentialBytes;

        string parameter = authorization.Parameter;
        string[] converted = parameter.Split('.');

        credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(converted[1]);

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        encoding = (Encoding)encoding.Clone();
        encoding.DecoderFallback = DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback;

        string decodedCredentials;

        decodedCredentials = encoding.GetString(credentialBytes);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(decodedCredentials))
        {
            return;
        }

        int colonIndex = decodedCredentials.IndexOf(':');

        if (colonIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }

        string[] colonArray = decodedCredentials.Split('"');
        string encrpytedEmail = colonArray[3];
        string encryptedPassword = colonArray[7];
        string digitCode = colonArray[11];

        var schema = symmetricCryptograperManager.GetSymmetricCryptographer(SymmetricCryptographyStrategy.DESCryptography, "000" + digitCode);

        string email = schema.Decrypt(encrpytedEmail);
        string password = schema.Decrypt(encryptedPassword);

        Tuple<string, string> emailAndPassword = new Tuple<string, string>(email, password);

        //authentication codes continues..
    }
```

I put breakpoints  on these classes to check whether the encrypted data I sent to and received from database is the same. Yes, they are the same.

This is what I get from `schema.Decrypt(encrpytedEmail)`:
h\0��\u0018���547@gmail.com
Which expected to be: ozgur547@gmail.com

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the IV handling correctly. You really don't want to reuse a cryptographic algorithm or `XCryptoServiceProvicer` and there is no need to. Just remember the secret key and you can generate another one of these lightweight objects. The IV should be stored together with the ciphertext; currently the first block of plaintext indicates a different IV value used during encryption / decryption.

---

Of course, DES is not a modern cryptographic primitive; try AES. I could try and start explaining crypto and how your code needs to be described in a protocol that fends off the attacks in specific attack scenarios, but that's too much for StackOverflow (or my time, for that matter).

Beware of wrapper classes that just exist to put in code *your understanding* of crypto; you'll definitely be wondering later on why you wrote them in the first place.